# Django, get an attribute from a model

Tags: python, django, attributes, return, django-queryset

I'm trying to get the value of a field from a model. The thing is that I'm getting the `id` if I use `filter(pk=university)`. But what it returns is `[{'name': u'Icecream Chocolate'}]`. Is it possible to get its name without the `[{'name': u' ... }]`?

```
item_name = Icecream.objects.filter(pk=icecream_id).values('name')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `objects.get()`:

```
item_name = Icecream.objects.get(pk=icecream_id).name
```

Or, if you still want to use `filter()`, but don't want to see dictionary with `name` key, use `values_list()` with `flat=True`:

```
item_name = Icecream.objects.get(pk=icecream_id).values_list('name', flat=True)
```

Comment: Yes you're correct! Thought it was going to be more complicated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the next section down in the docs:

```
item_name = Icecream.objects.filter(pk=icecream_id).values_list('name')
```